# How to use Yahoo's Weather XML file

Tags: javascript, php, xml, yahoo-weather-api

How do you load the XML file from

```
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12766488&u=f
```

and how do you use it.  I can either use JavaScript or PHP, but whenever I try with JavaScript, it throws this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12766488&u=f. Origin http://localhost:6574 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: And btw what now? If PHP works, why don't you use PHP for that. Just asking, it's not so clear from your quesiton. Or you *need* that in Javascript but you already could get it to work with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP as a proxy. Request to your domain (yes, you do AJAX), sending it the url you want to view:

```
http://mydomain.com/external.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fweather.yahooapis.com%2Fforecastrss%3Fw%3D12766488%26u%3Df
```

Then have a PHP page (`external.php` in this case) get the requested external URL and retrieve the external URL's contents using some function like [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Then whatever is returned by that request, return the results back as response to your AJAX.

```
echo file_get_contents(urlencode($_GET['url']));
```